# Search for letter or string in C

Tags: c, string, search

I am very new to C programming. I have extensive background in other web dev languages. I looked up simple number game online and copied and pasted. To check my understanding I commented some things as well. I tried to debug and realized that when a string is entered the entire code breaks. I just need a quick answer to something very basic: How to find letters in string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/*Attempting to optimize number game in C*/
// immediate bug: runs FOREVER if text is entered


int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL)); //I do not know 
    int r = rand() % 10 + 1; //Random number
    int correct = 0; //number correct from guess
    int guess; // Instance of guess
    int counter = 0; // Counter; how many tries
    const char* characters["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];// this is my var/*
    int c = 0, count[26] = { 0 }, x;
    */

    char string = [100];
    printf("Guess my number! "); // Does not need to repeat because of conditional statements below...

    do { //Runs at least once... [
        scanf("%d", &guess); // Takes in a number %d = int  
/*
        while (string[c] != '\0') {
            if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') {
                x = string[c] - 'a';
                count[x]++
            }

            c++;
        }
*/
        if (guess ==)
        if()

        if (guess == r) {  // Check if true 
            counter++; // Increment counter by 1
            printf("You guessed correctly in %d tries! Congratulations!\n", counter); // 
            correct = 1;
        }

        if (guess < r) { // check if less than
            counter++;
            printf("Your guess is too low. Guess again. ");
        }

        if (guess > r) { // check if more than 
            counter++;
            printf("Your guess is too high. Guess again. ");
        }
    } while (correct == 0); // If correct is null. ]

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you scan %d and input a string??

Comment: I can't tell what is commented out, or what you intend this code to do... why are so many chunks of code commented out? And what is `if (guess ==)`???

Comment: No that was comment. I didn't know what %d meant so I looked it up and typed it to memorize

Comment: `const char characters` should be `const char* characters`. The concept of pointers is required here.

Comment: All I am asking is how to scan strings for certain letters.

Comment: You would need to start with a "string", which is a pointer to characters (as Susmit already noted).

Comment: To be 100% honest I do not fully understand the concept of pointers

Comment: In C, there is no datatype called "String". Instead, character arrays are used to store text data. A pointer, in this case, is the starting address of the array.

Comment: @LucasBillips, kudos for admitting that. Pointers really are a fundamental part of C so I'd recommend you start out by reading up on them.

Comment: You can use this form of declaration to make it clearer: `const char characters[]`

Comment: @LucasBillips You should fix your sample code so that it can work.

Comment: **"How to find letters in string"** -- **"Which Letters?"** All, vowels, consonants, digits, uppercase, lowercase, alpha, alphanumeric, ...?

Comment: What bearing does the code in question have to do with finding letters?

Answer (score 0):

Standard C library has many functions for string manipulation, such as strcpy, strncpy,strlen, strchr, strcat and so on.
You can find letters in a string by using 'strchr' function.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   const char *astring="Stack Owerflow"; 
   char *ptr = strchr(astring, 'O');
   printf("Found:%c on position: %d\n",*ptr, ptr-astring);
}
```

/* Output:
Found:O on position: 6
*/